# Changing the TextView text from another View

Tags: android, xml, view

I have a Popup View and I am trying to change the values from another view before I inflate the view. But the problem is that the app crashes and gives an error that does not seem to be relevant at all, but then again if I remove the "changing" of the values it works. Adding the error here would not help because it is really specific about all the other classes.

So here is my Popup `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id = "@+id/more_info_popup_window"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#62def8">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_gray_score_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gray_user_star"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/silver_star_selected" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gray_star_points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="7777"
            android:textColor="@color/main_app_color"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.034"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gray_user_star"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I am inflating the view `onclick` like this:

```
userScoreConstraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int[] score = PostNewActivity.getScore();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = Objects.requireNonNull(inflater).inflate(R.layout.more_info_popup_window, null);

        // create the popup window
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

        // show the popup window
        // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        // dismiss the popup window when touched
        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this works fine, the popup comes up like it should. 
But before that when I call :

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gray_star_points)).setText("23");
```

The whole thing just crashes. Is it possible to give the solution based on this information?

Comment: add the log cat of crash portion please

Comment: @TouhidulIslam added the log, even tho it probably wont help

Comment: Where do you put this code `((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gray_star_points)).setText("23");`?

Comment: out of curiosity. why do you need to change the values before inflating? in my knowledge it is not possible to change a value of something that dosen't exist am i wrong?

Comment: @CharanM right before the "onclick" function or in the onclick function before inflating

Comment: @MasterFathi heh.. that was actually it, after inflating and using the view that I inflated the popup with to set the text, it started working, so thank you.

Comment: then please mark my answer as correct. glad i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inflate the view before changing it's values. you can't change the values of something that dosen't exist.